# Access is denied when saving changes to file in a Web Site on Windows Server 2012 using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, iis, windows-server-2012

Access is denied when saving changes to file in a Web Site on Windows Server 2012 running under IIS using Visual Studio, however I can save to the Desktop of the server and then copy to the same location in the Web Site and it works fine other then prompting me saying I need administrative permissions (which I have). Click ok and it copies fine.

How do I make it so that Visual Studio running on the server can save changes to files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open visual studio as Administrator with right click -> run as administrator. You may have admin rights, but it should be ran with the system's admin account to be able to save the changes you make.

Let me know if it was such an issue.